# Better mongo db schema to store user related info

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let say I have to store in mongoDB some data (say 'state') related to a particular User account.

What is the better option to do this: Collection state:

1) {id: - that will be the same in Users collection, [state data]}

2) {id: - some unique id for state, userId - id from user collection, [state data]}

So what would be better design decision?

Comment: What is your state data looks like?

Comment: Let say I'm going to store list of items bought by user and some user specific info about each Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you'll be accessing your data for your application. If every time you need to access the state, you will be fetching the User data anyway, it makes sense to store it in the User collection.

Think of Blogs and their Comments, you would never need to fetch the comments just by themselves, you always fetch the Blog entry and the related comments.

**EDIT:**
Some considerations:

1. If these lists that you speak of are all independent of each other, and there needs to be no referential integrities between lists of each user, then it makes sense to store them in Users collection
2. If you think User document will be bigger than 16MB (current max document size) then you might have to consider separating the collections (ie not storing all of the data in one place, Users collection)

Comment: What if I'm going to store list of items bought by user and some user specific Info about each Item? Is it good Idea to store all that stuff in User collection?